# Options for building a Android clock widget. Custom images as numbers or creating a font?

Tags: android

I want to build a digital clock widget for Android, and I have written the numbers from 1 to 10 on paper and scanned them, so that I now have the numbers as per images with transparent background. I may have missed it but I can't really see if in the documentation anything about using images as numbers. Would i be better off creating a font even though it would only consist of the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

First off: add each image separately to the res/drawable directory and reference them from there.

An Opengl surface could render them or, more easily I think, an ImageView with programmatic image flipping.

I'm working on the same thing. Any idea how to run an onTick()-like function for currentTimeMillis()? That would be the path to victory on when to render the next second on your clock face.